# VSCode Code Completion via CompletionItemProvider doesn't inherit completion for local variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, vscode-extensions

I'm currently writing a VSCode extension in TypeScript to provide Code Completion (IntelliSense) for my Lua API.
All works well, until I assign an Item to a variable, and try to get completion from the said variable.

```js
const rootProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('lua', {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext)
        {
            const genesisCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('genesis', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Module);
            const safecallCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('safecall', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method);
            safecallCompletion.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString()
            return [genesisCompletion, safecallCompletion]; 
        },
    });

    const libraryProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('lua', {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext)
        {
            const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.slice(0, position.character);
            if(!linePrefix.endsWith('genesis.')) { return undefined; }

            const cvarCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('cvar', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Module);
            const engineCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('engine', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Module);
            const renderCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('render', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Module);

            return [cvarCompletion, engineCompletion, renderCompletion];
        }
    }, '.');
```

Here you can see the ItemProviders, yes the actual providers work, however, in my Lua code when i do this:

```lua
local aaa = genesis
local bbb = aaa. -- no code completion here for the genesis "module".
                 -- it should in theory give intellisense for "aaa.cvar, aaa.engine, aaa.render"
```

GIF showing what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0zlZ.gif)

Comment: if you don't analyze your code to find out that `aaa` is a `genesis` you will not get completion, you have no code to get any info about `aaa` in front of the `.`